# save few state values to firestore react

Tags: reactjs, state

I want to save few details of the state value to firestore. How can I achieve that.?

State details

```
state = {
    loading: false,
    sp_name: '',
    sp_Phone: '',
    sp_Role: '',
    sp_Location: '',
    sp_Service: '',
    sp_country: '',
    sp_message: '',
    sp_License: ''
  }
```

I dont want to save loading state to firestore.

Handle submit event.

```
 handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
    this.props.UpdateUser(uid, this.state)
    this.setState({ loading: false })
    toast("Registered Successfully.!", { type: toast.TYPE.INFO, autoClose: 5000 });


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    const stateObj = this.state;
    delete stateObj['loading'];
    let uid = this.props.auth.uid;
    this.props.UpdateUser(uid, stateObj)
    this.setState({ loading: false })
    toast("Registered Successfully.!", { type: toast.TYPE.INFO, autoClose: 5000 });
  }
```